# Resample weekly data to quarterly or monthly without having uneven number of weeks

Tags: pandas, time-series

So I have weekly sales data:

```py
# Create the dataframe
test_df = pd.DataFrame({'year': [2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018], 'week': [9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17], 'sales': [100, 200, 100, 300, 200, 100, 200, 100, 300]})

# Convert the week and 
test_df['date'] = test_df["year"].astype(str) + '-' + test_df["week"].astype(str)
test_df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(test_df['date'] + '0', format='%Y-%W%w')
test_df
```

This is the resulting dataframe:

```
    year    week  sales date
0   2018    9     100   2018-03-04
1   2018    10    200   2018-03-11
2   2018    11    100   2018-03-18
3   2018    12    300   2018-03-25
4   2018    13    200   2018-04-01
5   2018    14    100   2018-04-08
6   2018    15    200   2018-04-15
7   2018    16    100   2018-04-22
8   2018    17    300   2018-04-29
```

Now I would like to smooth this data out and resample it to months or quarters, in order to make more stable long term predictions. However, when I resample the data to quarterly or monthly data, each period will have an uneven number of weeks, some 4 and some 5 (or 13, 12, 11 in the case of quarterly):

```py
test_df = test_df.set_index('date')
test_df = test_df.resample('M').sum()
test_df.drop(columns=['year', 'week'])
```

This gives:

```
            sales
date    
2018-03-31  700
2018-04-30  900
```

Now for months, I understand, months have different numbers of weeks. However, quarters should always have the same number of weeks if the first week start on January 1st, right?

My question is, am I missing something in the conversion from year-week -> date? This would be an issue if I create different subsequences out of this to train a prediction model.

Comment: Neither 365 (days in a non-leap year) nor 366 are even multiples of 7, so year quarters will not have equal numbers of weeks in them, no matter on which day a "week" starts. A quick example: `for x in ['SUN', 'W-MON', 'W-TUE', 'W-WED', 'W-THU', 'W-FRI', 'W-SAT']: print(pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range('2018-01-01', '2018-12-31', freq='W-SUN')).resample('QS').size())`